# CSV File Not Supported Error

Tags: import, csv

Here is the code:

```
import bpy
import csv
import sys
csv_path = sys.argv[1]

file = open(csv_path)
reader = csv.reader(file)

header = next(reader) # 1st line is header

data = [ ]
for row in reader:
    name0 = row[0]
    name1 = row[0]
    pathout = 'test-videos/' + row[5] + '.m4v'
    s = bpy.context.scene
    f = s.objects['FirstName']
    f.data.body = name0
    f1 = s.objects['FirstName01']
    f1.data.body = name1+'?'
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = pathout
    bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)

bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```

And here is the error message:

```
Read blend: /PI-SAT/proj001/proj001-master.blend
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/PI-SAT/proj001/proj001master.py", line 9, in <module>
header = next(reader) # 1st line is header
File"/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/python/
lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 23:
invalid continuation byte
Error: File format is not supported in file '/PI-SAT/proj001/test.csv'
... opened default scene instead; saving will write to
/PISAT/proj001/test.csv
```

I have read the file with a different script using the exact same code as in lines 2 - 15 and then printing the names and pathout. Running the script from the command line, not from within Blender, it works perfectly.

I have also run the part of the script within the for loop outside of the loop as a script from the command line and it works perfectly.

What am I missing about the CSV file? I created it in Excel on my Mac; is that a problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with Blender. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) would be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: This only happens when running the Python script from inside Blender. It has everything to do with Blender.

Comment: maybe try to share more info about the csv content, or a sample, if not all, of your csv file, it could help to spot what is not working... maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I think the file encoding is the problem.
The blender python assumes 'UTF-8' and maybe the command line gets the encoding from the system.

Try to give the open method a encoding:

```
file = open(csv_path, encoding='latin-1')
```

I think 'latin-1' is correct for Mac, otherwise try 'iso-8859-1' or 'cp1252'.

Comment: I think you may be onto something, but none of the three encodings solved the problem.

Comment: I have tried opening test.csv in BBEdit and saving it as UTF-8 and it did not work. Neither did an attempt with Latin-1.

Comment: I did a bit more looking, specifically for "codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 23".

I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1.

I ran:
    $ echo $LANG
The response was:
    en_US.UTF-8

Another great idea bites the dust.

Answer (score 0):

I changed:
    file = open(csv_path)
to:
    file = open(csv_path, 'rU', 'ignore')

This got rid of the:
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 23:
    invalid continuation byte

Comment: Ignoring encoding errors isn't a proper solution. Ask the person who produced the file which encoding they used.

Comment: I produced the file and used UTF-8. When that did not work, I also tried Latin-1.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing on the Mac. I have moved the project to Google Cloud and the program runs properly on Google Compute Engine.