# Blender not accepting CSV file

Tags: python, import, csv

[CSV File Not Supported Error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119381/csv-file-not-supported-error) dealt with the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 23:
invalid continuation byte
```

Now there is a different problem. The code is:

```
import bpy
import csv
import sys

file = open('test.csv', 'rU', 'ignore')
reader = csv.reader(file)
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
Error: File format is not supported in file '/PI-SAT/proj001/test.csv'
```

I have verified that test.csv is a valid .csv file by running a different script:

```
import csv

path = "test.csv"
file = open(path,'rU')
reader = csv.reader(file)

header = next(reader) # 1st line is header
#data = [row for row in reader] # Read remaining data
print(header)

data = []
for row in reader:
name0 = row[0]
name1 = row[0]
vid_file = 'test-videos/' + row[5] + '.m4v'
cli_line = name0 + '", "' + name1 + '", "' + vid_file
print(cli_line)
```

This runs exactly as expected as a stand alone Python script.

What is causing the error when I attempt to run the code as a Python script in Blender?

Comment: Please do not ask duplicate questions just because you did not get satisfactory answers on the first.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you tell the open function to [ignore errors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) with `open(..., 'ignore')` . If a file is not found, it will have the behavior that you mentioned:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Also, the `U` mode is deprecated, so you probably shouldn't be using it.

A reasonable possibility is that where you are running it in Blender, the current working directory is different than what you think it is. Try printing out the result of `os.getcwd()` and `os.listdir()` like so:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())   # current directory
print(os.listdir())  # files in current directory
```

Comment: I modified the code to work in Blender and got:   
 
`Read blend: /PI-SAT/proj001/proj001-master.blend  

/PI-SAT/proj001
["'pathout'", '__init__.py', 'b-csv-test.py', 'blank.blend', 'blank.blend1', 'blender', 'c-csv-test.py', 'csv-test.py', 'd-csv-test.py', 'env',  'lib', 'master_csv_render.py', 'oauth.py', 'pathout', 'pathout.m4v', 'proj001-master .blend.save', 'proj001-master.blend', 'proj001-master.blend1', 'proj001auto.py', 'proj001auto.py.save', 'proj001master.py',  'test-videos', 'test.blend', 'test.csv', 'testreadauto.py', 'testsubprocess.py']  

Blender quit`

Comment: I am in the correct directory, and the file is there.

Comment: @mcgeo52 I don't know exactly what you are doing...and your question is missing some detail. Could you edit your question to explain what you are trying to accomplish and where/how exactly you are running your Python script?

Answer (score 0):

I was testing on the Mac. I have moved the project to Google Cloud and the program runs properly on Google Compute Engine.